# How can I import kotlin functions to java classes?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am currently using KotlinModule class in my java file by importing `import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule;`, but in recent jackson library upgrade (using 2.13) it is has been depricated. I was looking for the new convention, and came across this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin#usage

however I am not able to load the recommended functions in java file, i think that only works in Kotlin file. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module uses Kotlin extension functions, they are all defined in an Extensions.kt file and as such are accessible by importing the ExtensionsKt class. For example :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = ExtensionsKt.jacksonObjectMapper();
```

If the method extends a type, for example in Kotlin :

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
```

The method is defined in kotlin as :

```
fun ObjectMapper.registerKotlinModule(): ObjectMapper
```

It will be converted in java to :

```
public static final ObjectMapper registerKotlinModule(@NotNull ObjectMapper $this$registerKotlinModule)
```

So to use it, you need to pass the extended type :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ExtensionsKt.registerKotlinModule(new ObjectMapper());
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to mimic the second approach of 
```val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()```  using extensions?

Comment: @denise I've updated the answer for this specific case.